# How to Bind a Model that contains an IEnumerables class

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a front end calling an axios request to a web api in ASP.NET Core and for some reason my model will not bind. I am sending email data to the web api and trying to bind it to an email and contact model. It just keeps showing the email object as null. My axios request seems to be working okay as it does send the payload but errors out in the API due to the email object being null.

JS

```
                axios({
                method: 'post',
                url: window.location.origin + '/MainReview/SendEmail',
                data: {
                    From: this.emailFrom,
                    To: this.emailToModel,
                    Cc: this.emailCcModel,
                    Bcc: this.emailBccModel,
                    Subject: this.emailSubject,
                    Body: this.emailBody,
                },
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
                    "RequestVerificationToken": document.forms[0].querySelector('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').value,
                }
            }).then(response => {

            }).catch(error => {
                console.log(error.response.data.error);
            });
```

Web API

```
        [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult SendEmail([FromBody] Email email)
    {

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(email.From);

        return Ok(new { Result = email.From });
    }
```

Model:

```
public class Email
{
    public string? From { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Contact>? To { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Contact>? Cc { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Contact>? Bcc { get; set; }
    public string? Subject { get; set; }
    public string? Body { get; set; }

}

public class Contact
{
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
}
```

Json data sent in payload:

```
{ "From":"emailfrom@example.com", "To":[ { "EMAIL_ADDRESS":"emailTo@example.com" }, { "EMAIL_ADDRESS":"emailCC@example.com" } ], "Cc":[ { "EMAIL_ADDRESS":"emailCC2@example.com" } ], "Bcc":[ ], "Subject":"Temporary Placeholder", "Body":"tessdf" }
```

I believe my issue is something with the IEnumerable. I will be honest I have stayed away from models but I figure I will start trying to use them more since its best practice. However, this is driving me nuts as I do not see why this would not work.

Comment: Not sure how do you get the json object, anyway your property name is `EmailAddress` instead of `EMAIL_ADDRESS`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.You use `[FromBody]` in backend and post json data in frontend, the `Content-Type` should be `application/json`.

```
headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',    //change here....
    "RequestVerificationToken": document.forms[0].querySelector('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').value,
}
```

2.The posted json data is not correct because the property in `Contact` model is named `EmailAddress`, but you post json with name `EMAIL_ADDRESS`.

```
data: { "From":"emailfrom@example.com", "To":[ { "EmailAddress":"emailTo@example.com" }, { "EmailAddress":"emailCC@example.com" } ], "Cc":[ { "EmailAddress":"emailCC2@example.com" } ], "Bcc":[ ], "Subject":"Temporary Placeholder", "Body":"tessdf" },
```

Comment: This is correct but what if the two are not one to one in naming? Can i bind a name property to model to make work?

Comment: Also if i removed the property name email_address  and just made email list a simple array can C# bind the model still to an inumerate?

Comment: No matter the relationship, just keep the name match will work.

Answer (score 2):

Ensure the structure matches methods parameter class.
Here, we've got an email parameter, which is an object {}.  And it also has properties which are a list of objects [{}].

```
data: {
            From: this.emailFrom,
            To: [{ EmailAddress: this.emailToModel }],
            Cc: [{ EmailAddress: this.emailCcModel }],
            Bcc: [{ EmailAddress: this.emailBccModel }],
            Subject: this.emailSubject,
            Body: this.emailBody,
    }
```

Note: If you were passing more than one parameter you need to specify the parameter name as well, with an extra set of {}.

```
data: {
        email: {
            From: this.emailFrom,
            To: [{ EmailAddress: this.emailToModel }],
            Cc: [{ EmailAddress: this.emailCcModel }],
            Bcc: [{ EmailAddress: this.emailBccModel }],
            Subject: this.emailSubject,
            Body: this.emailBody,
        },
        parameter2:"XXXXXXXXX"
    }
```

Comment: Should Data also be wrapped in [] because the examples i have found online just use {} and not [{}] for the parent . Also, my json property is EMAIL_ADDRESS but my model is EmailAddress. Anyway to link the two even if the names dont match?

Comment: @Bradyboyy88.  I've edited my answer.   Objects are wrapped in {}, arrays/lists are wrapped in [].